# How to hide "Right-click to run Adobe Flash Player"

Tags: google-chrome, adobe, flash

We use Flash-based solutions in our project. While page loading visitors can see small annoying window at bottom left corner saying "Right-click to run Adobe Flash Player".

Is there a way to hide that message?

[image: See screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

> *"Is there a way to hide that message?"*

- **1)** Make the SWF bigger (minimum w=800 by h=600).
- **2)** Or make sure the SWF is loaded from same domain/folder as rest of page content.